LyX outline pane: Selected section appears at bottom
Here's an example to illustrate what I mean.
I have many sections. In section 45, I have the text "yyy". When I click on "yyy", the outline pane does go to section 45, but puts it at the bottom. (I don't think this was the usual behavior before LyX 2.4.)

How can I change this behavior so that the outline pane has section 45 either in the middle:

Or at the top:

LyX and Windows version I'm using:


Could you please post an example .lyx file so it's easy to play around with things?

@scottkosty: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1hH3gJsix1FM0p0n8W608S0p55JsEQrl_/view?usp=sharing

Thanks. I can reproduce on Linux on 2.4.1. I checked 2.3.x and there it shows up as 2nd-to-last (i.e., 1 above the bottom). I am not sure you can change the current behavior easily.

Are you interested in compiling LyX? If so, we can provide a patch for you that you can apply and compile and get the behavior that you want. Honestly, I wouldn't recommend this unless you already have experience with compiling program source code, or by chance you've been waiting to give it a try. It's kind of a pain to get things set up how you like. But if this issue really itches you, it could be something to consider.

@scottkosty: Thanks for the suggestion but I think I'll give that a pass
